# Bug with y axis minor ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, yticks

Minor ticks on the y-axis are not placed as they should be. I set the minor locator to 2 so there should be 1 minor tick between each major tick but ticks on the bottom of the y-axis and none at the middle and on the top of axis.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.ticker import (AutoMinorLocator)

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(n=2)

#a je 2-->1

a_1_2 = np.array([0,12.3787177960363,0,12.3787177960363,0,0,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,13.4102776123727,0,10.3155981633636,0,10.3155981633636,0,14.441837428709,0,14.441837428709,0,15.4733972450454,0,15.4733972450454,0,13.4102776123727,0,20.6311963267272,0,20.6311963267272,0,0,0,18.5680766940545,0,18.5680766940545])

a_1_2[a_1_2==0] = np.nan

#b je 1-->2

b_1_2 = np.array([12.3787177960363,0,12.3787177960363,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,10.3155981633636,0,10.3155981633636,0,14.441837428709,0,14.441837428709,0,15.4733972450454,0,15.4733972450454,0,13.4102776123727,0,20.6311963267272,0,20.6311963267272,0,18.5680766940545,0,0,0,18.5680766940545,0])

b_1_2[b_1_2==0] = np.nan

#c je 2-->3

c = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18.5680766940545,0,0,0,0])

c[c==0] = np.nan

#d je 3-->2

d = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18.5680766940545,0,0,0])

d[d==0] = np.nan

vykon_1_2 = np.array([70,37,68,33,62,131,125,21,58,118,114,19,64,21,60,21,90,78,80,71,74,71,70,70,82,54,75,44,68,61,70,129,123,56,71,53])

a_1_04 = np.array([0,16.480541444427,0,16.480541444427,0,13.7337845370225,0,13.7337845370225,0,10.987027629618,0,10.987027629618,0,0,8.24027072221352,16.480541444427,0,0,15.1071629907248,0,15.1071629907248,0,19.2272983518315,0,12.3604060833203,0,9.61364917591577])

a_1_04[a_1_04==0] = np.nan

b_1_04 = np.array([16.480541444427,0,16.480541444427,0,16.480541444427,0,13.7337845370225,0,13.7337845370225,0,10.987027629618,0,10.987027629618,8.24027072221352,0,0,16.480541444427,15.1071629907248,0,15.1071629907248,0,19.2272983518315,0,12.3604060833203,0,9.61364917591577,0])

b_1_04[b_1_04==0] = np.nan

vykon_1_04 = np.array([80,44,65,44,67,36,78,36,79,60,79,61,80,99,90,54,70,85,39,85,39,72,67,102,48,128,127])

a_0_8 = np.array([0,27.8521150410817,0,27.8521150410817,0,32.4941342145953,0,32.4941342145953])

a_0_8[a_0_8==0] = np.nan

b_0_8 = np.array([27.8521150410817,0,27.8521150410817,0,32.4941342145953,0,32.4941342145953,0])

b_0_8[b_0_8==0] = np.nan

vykon_0_8 = np.array([105,100,101,97,97,95,98,94])

R_a_1_2 = 1.78*a_1_2*1.2e-3/(5.04e-5)

R_b_1_2 = 1.78*b_1_2*1.2e-3/(5.04e-5)

R_a_1_04 = 1.78*a_1_04*1.04e-3/(5.04e-5)

R_b_1_04 = 1.78*b_1_04*1.04e-3/(5.04e-5)

R_a_0_8 = 1.78*a_0_8*0.8e-3/(5.04e-5)

R_b_0_8 = 1.78*b_0_8*0.8e-3/(5.04e-5)

a_1_2 = pd.DataFrame(a_1_2)

b_1_2 = pd.DataFrame(b_1_2)

c = pd.DataFrame(c)

d = pd.DataFrame(d)

R_a_1_2 = pd.DataFrame(R_a_1_2)

R_b_1_2 = pd.DataFrame(R_b_1_2)

vykon_1_2 = pd.DataFrame(vykon_1_2)

a_1_04 = pd.DataFrame(a_1_04)

b_1_04 = pd.DataFrame(b_1_04)

R_a_1_04 = pd.DataFrame(R_a_1_04)

R_b_1_04 = pd.DataFrame(R_b_1_04)

vykon_1_04 = pd.DataFrame(vykon_1_04)

a_0_8 = pd.DataFrame(a_0_8)

b_0_8 = pd.DataFrame(b_0_8)

R_a_0_8 = pd.DataFrame(R_a_0_8)

R_b_0_8 = pd.DataFrame(R_b_0_8)

vykon_0_8 = pd.DataFrame(vykon_0_8)

data_1_2 = pd.concat([vykon_1_2, a_1_2,b_1_2,c,d], axis = 1)

data_1_04 = pd.concat([vykon_1_04, a_1_04,b_1_04], axis = 1)

data_0_8 = pd.concat([vykon_0_8, a_0_8,b_0_8], axis = 1)

data_R_1_2 = pd.concat([vykon_1_2, R_a_1_2,R_b_1_2,], axis = 1)

data_R_1_04 = pd.concat([vykon_1_04, R_a_1_04,R_b_1_04], axis = 1)

data_R_0_8 = pd.concat([vykon_0_8, R_a_0_8,R_b_0_8], axis = 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5), dpi = 100)

#figure(figsize=(8,5), dpi = 100)

#plt.plot(data.iloc[:,0],data.iloc[:,1],"v", color="#000000")

plt.ylabel('Výkon [W]')

plt.xlabel('Rychlost plynu [m/s]')

ax.plot(data_1_2.iloc[:,2],data_1_2.iloc[:,0],"v", color="#000000", label = "1,2 mm průměr")

ax.plot(data_1_04.iloc[:,2],data_1_04.iloc[:,0],"s", color="#ff0000", label = "1,04 mm průměr")

ax.plot(data_0_8.iloc[:,2],data_0_8.iloc[:,0],"o", color="#0000ff", label = "0,8 mm průměr")

ax.legend()

#plt.plot(data_1_2.iloc[:,2],data_1_2.iloc[:,0])

#plt.plot(data_1_2.iloc[:,3],data_1_2.iloc[:,0])

#plt.xlim(10, 140)

plt.yticks(np.arange(10,130+1, step=20))

ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)

plt.xticks(np.arange(5, 35+1, step=2.5))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)

plt.savefig("prechod_z_1_na_2.pdf")

#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(20))

#ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
```

and there is the result I get:

[image]

Comment: I think that [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78187105/2749397) addresses the WHY it doesn't work in your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Always use `ax.*axis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(n))`

---

When you use **the same instance** of `AutoMinorLocator` twice, something bad is going to happen.

I **guess* that

1. when an `AutoMinorLocator` is associated with an axis, an internal data structure is written with a list of ticks' positions
2. when you associate the same instance, for you `minor_locator`, to two axis, the internal data is correct for the last axis only, because the internal data is overwritten
3. when you use `plt.show()` only one axis is associated with the correct data structure (the last one that was associated), while the *first* axis ticks are placed according to list of positions  found for the *second* one.

Here follows an example.

First subplot, same instance, first used on *x* and then on *y*, y ticks are OK, on x the ticks are on 16.67 and 23.33, i.e., the same two positions on y!
Second subplot, same instance, first *y* then *x*, x ticks are OK, the y ticks are in the same positions as the x ticks, the last minor y tick is at 35, more or less...
Third subplot, using two different, fresh instances, then both axes' ticks are OK.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

#Number of Minor Ticks
nmt = 3

b_1_2 = np.array([12.3787177960363,0,12.3787177960363,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,13.4102776123727,0,0,0,10.3155981633636,0,10.3155981633636,0,14.441837428709,0,14.441837428709,0,15.4733972450454,0,15.4733972450454,0,13.4102776123727,0,20.6311963267272,0,20.6311963267272,0,18.5680766940545,0,0,0,18.5680766940545,0])
b_1_04 = np.array([16.480541444427,0,16.480541444427,0,16.480541444427,0,13.7337845370225,0,13.7337845370225,0,10.987027629618,0,10.987027629618,8.24027072221352,0,0,16.480541444427,15.1071629907248,0,15.1071629907248,0,19.2272983518315,0,12.3604060833203,0,9.61364917591577,0])
b_0_8 = np.array([27.8521150410817,0,27.8521150410817,0,32.4941342145953,0,32.4941342145953,0])

vykon_1_2 = np.array([70,37,68,33,62,131,125,21,58,118,114,19,64,21,60,21,90,78,80,71,74,71,70,70,82,54,75,44,68,61,70,129,123,56,71,53])
vykon_1_04 = np.array([80,44,65,44,67,36,78,36,79,60,79,61,80,99,90,54,70,85,39,85,39,72,67,102,48,128,127])
vykon_0_8 = np.array([105,100,101,97,97,95,98,94])

for v in (b_1_2, b_1_04, b_0_8): v[v==0] = np.nan

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(7, 10), layout='constrained')
for n, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):

  ax.plot( b_1_2,  vykon_1_2, "v", color="#000000", label = "1,20 mm průměr")
  ax.plot(b_1_04, vykon_1_04, "s", color="#ff0000", label = "1,04 mm průměr")
  ax.plot (b_0_8,  vykon_0_8, "o", color="#0000ff", label = "0,80 mm průměr")

  ax.set_xticks(np.arange(5, 35+1, step=2.5))
  ax.set_yticks(np.arange(10,130+1, step=20))
  minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(nmt)
  if n==0:
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)  
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
  elif n==1:
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
  else:
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(nmt))
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(nmt))
      
  ax.set_xlabel('Rychlost plynu [m/s]')
  ax.set_ylabel('Výkon [W]')
  ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks, it works! I didn't think that it could go this wrong using one Auto_minor_locator for all axes

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(n=2)

# your data 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5), dpi=100)

plt.ylabel('Výkon [W]')
plt.xlabel('Rychlost plynu [m/s]')

ax.plot(data_1_2.iloc[:,2], data_1_2.iloc[:,0], "v", color="#000000", label="1,2 mm průměr")
ax.plot(data_1_04.iloc[:,2], data_1_04.iloc[:,0], "s", color="#ff0000", label="1,04 mm průměr")
ax.plot(data_0_8.iloc[:,2], data_0_8.iloc[:,0], "o", color="#0000ff", label="0,8 mm průměr")
ax.legend()

plt.yticks(np.arange(10, 130+1, step=20))
plt.xticks(np.arange(5, 35+1, step=2.5))

# minor tick placement on y-axis is adjusted here
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
minor_ticks_y = np.arange(15, 130, 20)  # Define minor tick positions manually
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks_y, minor=True)

plt.savefig("prechod_z_1_na_2.pdf")
plt.show()
```

In this code, minor_ticks_y is defined as an array of positions where we want the minor ticks to be located on the y-axis. This array can be adjusted according to desired minor tick positions. Then, set these ticks using ax.set_yticks(), specifying minor=True to indicate that these are minor ticks. Adjust the positions in minor_ticks_y array the way you want

Comment: thanks, it works! But do you know why my solution works for axis x and doesn't work for axis y?